# Conditional in django model field declaration

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model called `Image`, which I use to store both paintings and photos. 
In this model, I have an `Artist` field, which stores the name of the creator.

For reasons uninportant to the question, `Artist` *can* be blank if the Image instance is a photo, but it *can not* be blank if the `Image` instance is a painting. As such, I would want something like such:

```
class Image(models.Model)

    isPainting = models.BooleanField(default=0) # set too 1 for paintings
    artist = models.CharField(
        max_length=127, 
        if isPainting:
            blank=False
        else:
            blank=True
    )
```

Is such a conditional possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do is declare the field with `blank=True` and override de `clean` method of your form to make sure an artist is specified if `isPainting` is `True`.

**Models.py**

```
class Image(models.Model)

    isPainting = models.BooleanField(default=0) # set too 1 for paintings
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=127, blank=True)
```

**Forms.py**

```
 def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(ImageForm, self).clean()
    isPainting = cleaned_data.get("isPainting")
    artist = cleaned_data.get("artist")

    if isPainting and not artist :
        raise ValidationError('An artist must be specified since it is a painting')

    return cleaned_data
```

This will forbid not adding an artist if isPainting is `True`